# Generate current by microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, current, current-source

I have to generate current values between 0mA to 110mA.
Can I generate current automatically using a micro-controller? (For example: 20mA , 30mA...)
I need to keep the current stable for ms in frequency between 1Hz-100Hz.

If so, how?

Comment: Do you want to generate constant current, or are these just the maximum values that you need to supply somewhere?

Comment: Generally micros only have digital outputs, but some have a digital to analog converter built in (such as microchip PIC24FJ128GC010 family).  Regarding control over the current, this can be very easy if the load is known and simple (such as a constant resistance), but will be somewhat more complicated if it is unknown or varying.  I think you will get much more useful answers if you can tell us about the load :)

Comment: I would like to add that, while the first inquiry of this question could be beneficial, the second inquiry regarding recommended microcontrollers is off topic for this stackexchange site as that information would go out of date fairly quickly and the answer many not be helpful to most people.

Comment: @Sensors I actually would not argue that to be honest.  As MikeP noted, the controllers capable of this would be ones with DACs, as such there would be very little to no additional hardware needed and the reasoning as to why it is off-topic still stands.  If OP was asking about discrete analog type solutions, then I would see it being on topic, but since all the electronic would would be done for him inside a microcontroller, there is nothing to be useful in the long run for others.

Comment: @Funkyguy - There! Removed the request for MCUs from the question.

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks! Not trying to be anal about it, it just supports the longevity of the site.  If you like, we can discuss the microcontroller part in the chat room and we can help you out more specifically in there.

Comment: @Funkyguy - No need to discuss it. You're doing a great job, keep it up! Just felt sad about the question going to waste just because of that line. As you said, the design part of the question is interesting. So I just wanted to see what comes up as answers, before it gets closed as too broad :D

Comment: @Golaž I  want to generate constant current.@MikeP  The load is unknown (the resistance can change).

Comment: @mak How accurate do you need to control the current (e.g. 1mA, 10mA, ...)? Also how close does the output current needs to be to what is set (e.g. 1%, 5%, ...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constant current can be generated by a microcontroller by using feedback and designing a control system that can monitor the output current and adjust the output accordingly. Most microcontrollers will not be able to source 110 mA on any of the I/O so you would at least need an amplifier or switching element (such as a FET).

One common solution would be to use one of the PWM outputs of the microcontroller to switch an NFET at a high frequency with the load connected between the positive supply and the drain of the NFET. A shunt resistor is connected between the source terminal of the NFET and ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2UVlj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The control system running on the microcontroller would then modulate the PWM duty cycle based on the current reading (measured as the voltage across the shunt resistor). The example shown above is a rudimentary outline of this design. Designing the control system software is non-trivial and will require some reading and experimentation if you have no previous experience.

Comment: This circuit won't work without some filtering somewhere in the loop to convert the PWM output into an analog signal.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a high-power current-mode DAC which could do this, but couldn't find one; most true DACs only work to a few milliwatts.

Edit: What might be a better solution than the following is a [Linear Tech LT3092](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3092fb.pdf) 200mA, 2-terminal programmable current source. It has a minimum current limit of 0.5mA however. Use an R2R ladder from open-collector outputs to generate the "Set" resistor value, or send the "Set" pin 0-1v directly.

---

If the target max voltage is 5v and the microcontroller (or even discrete logic) is 5v, and if each pin can source some known maximum current (say 20mA)... then output 8 or 16 bits of binary data, based on a setpoint you input. (By "output" I mean "high" and "tri-state", not "low.") Route the binary output through a series of limit resistors, where  each value is twice the first: (MSB 250Ω, 500Ω, 1kΩ, 2k, 4k, 8k, 16k, 32k LSB), etc. Tie all of these together (with a 100nF ceramic cap to ground) and feed the load with it directly. Use schottky protection diodes if needed.

A logic high on any pin contributes (20mA - that limit resistor) of current. Since they sum, the total output is the binary sum of each /2 current. For one 8-bit port, it would be 20mA + 10 + 5 + 2.5 + 1.25 + 0.625 + 0.3125 + 0.15625mA = 39.84375mA. Use 4 bits of another port with 250Ω resistors for 0-80mA (in 20mA steps) "course" adjustment, then the 8-bit word for fine adjustment.

Now where this will not work well, is into a load which drops voltage, such as an LED. The dropped voltage will manifest as less-than-expected current. In that case, a current-sense resistor may be a better idea than a statically-set word value, and the current sampled and binary output adjusted (increased) accordingly. But be careful of oscillation.

The benefit of this approach is that the output is linearly adjustable across the entire range (resolution limited only by the number of bits), and there is vastly less ripple current in the load. The only ripple present is at the transition of the binary state. If the load is static, there is zero ripple. In a worst-case scenario, if an 8-bit LSB were toggling, that makes a change in the order of 5v/32k = 156uA. If it were 16-bit, that would be 5v/8.192MΩ = 610nA!

The downside to this approach is that it is quite inefficient in terms of power (linear), and uses many components. It's also assuming the logic can source/dissipate 110mA of current, which undoubtedly exceeds some microcontroller limits and many discrete devices. The [PIC16F722A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41417B.pdf#page=199) for example, states:

`Total Power Disspation = 800mW`. (110mA + 15mA for the uC) * 5v = 625mW, so getting close to the limit but should be fine for 25°C applications. Use a ground plane or other means of dissipating heat. Set unused pins as inputs and ground-plane them.

`Maximum current sourced by all ports` is a little trickier, at 140mA for `Industrial` and 65mA for `Extended` devices. So the `Industrial` variant would be required. I'd try to spread out the 20mA pins in an attempt to balance the thermal load.